# I can't fetch a .deb file while using docker build

Tags: docker

Sorry but I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to build a container with this command:

`docker build -t aps-report .`

These are the contents of the dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod headers

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y wget curl libxrender1 libfontconfig libxtst6 xz-utils libjpeg62-turbo-dev xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base gvfs colord glew-utils libvisual-0.4-plugins gstreamer1.0-tools opus-tools qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5 qt5-qmltooling-plugins librsvg2-bin lm-sensors xvfb
RUN  wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN  dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.stretch_amd64.deb
RUN  cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/
RUN  cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin/

EXPOSE 80
```

On a side note, this is a project that I've cloned and this is the original dockerfile that came with it.

and this is the error that I'm experiencing.

```
279.9 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pcre2/libpcre2-16-0_10.36-2%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to 146.75.62.132:80: dial tcp 146.75.62.132:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [IP: 146.75.62.132 80]
279.9 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxext/libxext6_1.3.3-1.1_amd64.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to 146.75.62.132:80: dial tcp 146.75.62.132:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [IP: 146.75.62.132 80]
279.9 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/usb.ids/usb.ids_2023.01.16-0%2bdeb11u1_all.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to 146.75.62.132:80: dial tcp 146.75.62.132:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [IP: 146.75.62.132 80]
279.9 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried several things including downloading the single .deb files, trying to include them into my project but I had no luck so far.

Also I've tried editing my dockerfile and using --fix-missing too.

Comment: Usually, it's better with `apt-get` instead of `apt`. The later is not intended to be run in scripts.

Comment: Looks like a network issue from your host. Can you do `wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pcre2/libpcre2-16-0_10.36-2%2bdeb11u1_amd64.deb` without error?

Comment: I can run `docker build . ` with no issue on my side with your exact dockerfile.

Comment: @GillesQuénot yes, i get a 200. Also, I've edited the dockerfile with apt-get as you suggested. Still, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply separated this one line

```
RUN apt install -y wget curl libxrender1 libfontconfig libxtst6 xz-utils libjpeg62-turbo-dev xfonts-75dpi xfonts-base gvfs colord glew-utils libvisual-0.4-plugins gstreamer1.0-tools opus-tools qt5-image-formats-plugins qtwayland5 qt5-qmltooling-plugins librsvg2-bin lm-sensors xvfb
```

into separate lines:

```
RUN apt install -y wget curl libxrender1
RUN apt install -y wget curl libfontconfig
...
```

and so on.

Probably I had issues with my network, but I'm still not a 100% sure.